# .CA Domain registratrs for DNSSEC

Tags: dns, security, domain-registration, domain-registrar

We have a .ca (CIRA) domain that currently uses DNSSEC through the ISC DLV registry service.  We are aware that DLV is shutting down by 2017.  We have communicated with CIRA respecting .ca registrars that support DNSSEC but on contacting the first three we selected from their list we discovered that no, they do not actually do that, yet.  But real soon now. . .

I do not want to be fussing over this in a panic next December.  Nor to I wish to continue to leave messages and inquiries with registrars that either do not reply or do not yet actually provide the service.

What I would like is the name of a Canadian or Overseas DNR that someone has actually registered a .CA domain with through their non-beta accessible portal and has DNSSEC working for that domain with the user's own generated DS RR.

We run our own private CA for our certificates. If a Registrar has any restriction which effectively means that they must control the certificates then we are not interested in them.

We also run our own DNS servers.  So all we are interested in is the registry function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NamesPro can install your DS RR in the TLD zone, although they can't host your signed zone. It doesn't sound like that would be an issue for you.

It's a manual process, you have to open a ticket and supply them with the DS RR you want installed. But they did get it done pretty quick, maybe an hour on a Sunday.